# Firebase 3.0.1 web API querying isn't working, getting an iFrame security error

Tags: firebase

I did a simple call to `ref.once('value', callback)`. The callback never got called.

Instead I got this error in my Chrome console: `Refused to display 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project6...redacted...73&parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8204&pfname=&rpctoken=3...redacted...4' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.`

I have no idea what this iFrame is or whether that's why I didn't get a callback. FWIW, I'm running my dev app on `localhost:8204`

Edit:
Here's a fuller code sample.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: config.firebaseApiKey,
  authDomain: `${config.firebaseAppName}.firebaseio.com`,
  databaseURL: `https://${config.firebaseAppName}.firebaseio.com`,
  storageBucket: config.firebaseStorageBucket
})

const ref = firebase.database().ref()

ref.once('value', callback)
```

Comment: Could you include a fuller snippet of the code you're using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok the problem was simply in the initialization config `authDomain` field, I wrote `.firebaseio.com` but it should have been `.firebaseapp.com`.

Comment: same capy/paste