# Firebase: Facebook login auth/network-request-failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I've read all answers related to the same error here and didn't find any solution for me.
I also reinstalled `cordova-plugin-whitelist` - this didn't help me.
After clicking on "Login" button for a second I see a blank popup window then `auth/network-request-failed, A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred`. error in my code.

Here is my js code (sample from Firebase docs):

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
    'display': 'popup'
    });

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    deferred.resolve()
    // ...
}
).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
    // deferred.reject(err)
});
```

Here is my signup view code:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="background">

        <div class="holder">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>App name</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>


    <div class="bottom padding">
        <button class="button button-block button-green" ng-click="vm.loginFacebook()">
            LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK
        </button>
        <div class="terms">
            By signing in you agree to our
            <br>
            <a href="#" ng-click="vm.openUrl(1)">Terms of Services</a> and
            <a href="#" ng-click="vm.openUrl(2)">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</ion-view>
```

Does somebody have any ideas how to solve this ?

**UPDATE**

This issue can be reproduce only in Google Chrome and Edge. In the Firefox works properly

**UPDATE 2**

Not properly in Firefox, but strange thing happening, in Firefox I see a Google auth window for two seconds, then it closes itself and I have another error:

```
auth/network-request-failed. The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation.
```

Comment: What actual URL is that network error referring to?

Comment: @CBroe I saw a blank window even without url in it...Where I can find this url which you asking about ?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332039/firebase-3-0-1-web-api-querying-isnt-working-getting-an-iframe-security-error). That was simple typo, I wrote .firebaseio.com but it should have been .firebaseapp.com in the `authDomain` field.